# Re-index updated post and update cached AMP version

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, googlebot

I have a post I just updated on a site. This site gets picked up in google almost instantly but this post that I updated is not getting updated. As a matter of fact the post in mobile index, which is AMP, is showing the old post with no updated text, title and featured image. Below are the things I have changed in the post:

1. Added more text with an update
2. Added a new featured image
3. Added "Updated - 9/8/17" to the title
4. Updated meta title

**Things I have done to get the post picked up:**

1. Requested to re-crawl the page in Search Console.
2. Posted updated post on Twitter, Facebook and LinkedIn

**My site setup:**

1. XML Sitemap linked to Search Console
2. Structured data for articles in json format that includes: post title, post description, post published date, post last updated date, images, author and etc.
3. Google News active
4. AMP enabled

No idea why its not being picked up. Its been a few hours.I am concerned because this is a very important post designed to communicate with our customers about event cancellations due to Irma.

Should I change the publish date to now and request a crawl again?

Comment: If you are using the Google Search Console Fetch as Google, it can still take a couple of days for the regular googlebot to visit your page. This is because this feature, predictably, has been abused. It appears you have done what you can. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

If your post is in AMP be sure that after the update the real url of the post did not change! Otherwise for Google it will be another page. Some CMS for some reason change the ulr. For example your post was

```
https://yourdomain.com/yourcms/posts/good-pizza20170101.php
```

can became

```
https://yourdomain.com/yourcms/posts/good-pizza20170908.php
```

or something like that

Another things is that if the post is served in Google result as AMP the URL will be not your but probably the URL of the Google server where your post has been cached. To update the cache you must visit your post from the URL of the cache:

"To take advantage of the Google AMP Cache, an AMP URL must be accessed directly from the cache using the AMP Cache URL format. Each time a user accesses AMP content from the cache, the content is automatically updated, and the updated version is served to the next user once the content has been cached." at least this is what Google state: [AMP on Google](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/overview)